# scalaの環境構築が出来ません。

Tags: scala

javaはインストール出来ていると思うのですが、

```
>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_302
```

恐らく、stbがうまくインスト―ル出来ていないが故に、
IDEでscalaが使えません

```
C:\>sbt sbt-version
[warn] Neither build.sbt nor a 'project' directory in the current directory: "C:\"
c) continue
q) quit
?
```

追記

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\scala>sbt
[warn] Neither build.sbt nor a 'project' directory in the current directory: "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\scala"
c) continue
q) quit
?c
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\scala
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.6 (Temurin Java 1.8.0_302)
[info] set current project to scala (in build file:/C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/scala/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-5814c1c154581fd6564b
[info] started sbt server
sbt:scala>  println("Hello world")
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: println
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: println (similar: printWarnings, installSbtn, terminal)
[error] println("Hello world")
[error]        ^
```

なぜか、エラーが出てきます。
IDEで設定してもエラーが出ています。

どうすれば、いいのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

[Scalaの開発環境の準備: JDKとsbtのインストール](https://yoshinorin.net/2019/04/01/preparation-scala-install-adoptopenjdk-and-sbt/)によると、初回起動時はご質問のメッセージが表示されるようです。
`c`を入力してエンターキーを押すと環境構築処理が進みます。
(カレントディレクトリに`target`ディレクトリなどが作成されるため、Cドライブ直下ではなく作業用ディレクトリの作成が推奨されています)

Comment: なぜか、エラーが出て、Hello worldが表示されません。